# Adding elements in a list

Tags: python

I have a list named `p`. It contains some elements like this.

```
p = [['mon', '1006'], ['mon', '769']].
```

I want to add the values like `(1006 + 769)` and print the summation. How Can I do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you an idea.

```
p = [['mon', '1006'], ['mon', '769']]
sum = 0
for x in p:
    sum += int(x[1])
print sum
```

Run:

```
$ python 2.py
1775
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this by using a list comprehension, `_` is a throw away variable and you just use the second element `n` from the unpacking of the list items.

```
p = [['mon', '1006'], ['mon', '769']]
print sum(int(n) for _, n in p)
>1775
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic question, so you should probably work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/). Also, asking for the solution without attempting anything on your own won't teach you Python.

Here's the most straight forward, naive approach you could have come up with:

```
>>> p = [['mon', '1006'], ['mon', '769']]
>>> total = 0
>>> 
>>> for sublist in p:
...     value = sublist[1]
...     value_as_int = int(value)
...     total = total + value_as_int
... 
>>> print(total)
1775
```

That's just a `for` loop, basic summation and indexing into a list.
I'll spare you the fancier oneliners for now, I'm sure other answer will show you those.

Comment: Very clear code, a beginner can easily grasp this :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that you want to sum up the second values of the elements in your list, try this:

```
print(sum([int(element[1]) for element in p]))
```

Comment: Please correct the syntax around the `sum` function.

Comment: @Manjunath fixed. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce`,

```
l = [['mon', '1006'], ['mon', '769']]
print reduce(lambda item1, item2: int(item1[1])+int(item2[1]), l)

#output 1775
```